# I need to extract following data from xml file in bash mac:

Tags: xml, bash, macos, terminal, tags

I need to get the value of the number and file name from the following:

```
 <title><num>4.</num></title>

                    <header>Kurztitel für Kolumnentitel</header>

                    <bibl>Bibliographische Angaben zu den folgenden Schriftstücken</bibl>

                    <xmlfile name="1790-Verhandeling"/>
```

I should have as a result something like this using the mac bash terminal:

1790-Verhandeling,4

(1790-Verhandeling comes from "xmlfilename=" and the 4 from "num")

I thought of using something like this:

```
grep '<num>' myfile.xml | sed "s@.*<num>\(.*\)</num>.*@\1@"
```

But I don't know how to get the rest of the info I need

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...).

Comment: Your example is not valid XML.

Answer (score 0):

Easy solution:

```
grep -oP '<num>\K(\d+)|<xmlfile name="\K(.*?)(?=")' < myfile.xml | tac | paste -d',' - -
```

Grep:
-o is only match
-P enable Perl regular expressions
\K start match from it
(?=...) captured match must be followed by whatever is within the parentheses but that part isn't captured

Tac reverse order of matched lines

Paste (paste multiple lines in one single line):
-d is a delimiter, in our case we have choiced comma
- - make a single line from two lines to the time

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick answer, but I am getting the following results with the Mac Terminal: -bash: tac: command not found
usage: grep [-abcDEFGHhIiJLlmnOoqRSsUVvwxZ] [-A num] [-B num] [-C[num]]
 [-e pattern] [-f file] [--binary-files=value] [--color=when]
 [--context[=num]] [--directories=action] [--label] [--line-buffered]
 [--null] [pattern] [file ...]

Comment: Sorry for the basic questions, but I am very new to Grep and Perl ;)

Comment: @AndresFischer: Use GNU grep or better an XML/HTML parser.